# TensorFlow training - matching results with simple one layer estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am new to TensorFlow but experienced at analytics.  I am attempting to reproduce in TensorFlow the performance I obtain using a legacy Neural Network trainer, comprised simply of a single hidden-layer, trained using back-prop with momentum update and a mean-squared error objective function.

Unfortunately all my attempts have thus far failed, with TensorFlow models being produced that range from being roughly "only" 10-15% inferior to my home-brewed trainer when using the canned tf.estimator.DNNClassifier, to much, much worse when I try to construct the net myself.

Can someone identify the mistakes being made in how I am calling the tool in the code below?  Using a command line input, I toggle between the "canned_dnn" and my "custom" set up

```
def get_classifier( model_name, cur_model_dir, feature_columns ):
    if model_name == 'canned_dnn':
        return tf.estimator.DNNClassifier( feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                           model_dir=cur_model_dir,
                                           hidden_units=[18],
                                           activation_fn=tf.nn.relu )
    elif model_name == 'custom':
        return tf.estimator.Estimator( model_fn=my_model,
                                       model_dir=cur_model_dir,
                                       params={
                                           'feature_columns': feature_columns,
                                           'n_classes': 2
                                       })
    else:
        raise RuntimeError()

def my_model(features, labels, mode, params):

    # input layer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    net = tf.feature_column.input_layer( features, params['feature_columns'] )

    # hidden layer 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=18, activation=tf.nn.relu, use_bias=True, bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), name='LEARN_1')

    # output layer computes logits                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name='OUTPUT')

    # compute predictions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {
            'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
            'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
            'logits': logits,
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

    # mean squared error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=tf.one_hot(labels, 2), predictions=logits)

    # metrics                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    # loss report                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss )

    # accuracy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                                   predictions=predicted_classes,
                                   name='acc_op')

    metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

    # EVALUATION MODE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

    # TRAINING MODE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    with tf.name_scope( 'OPTIMIZE' ):
        optimizer=tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=.02,momentum=.5)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```